# Angular 2, which approach I should take for showing a loading indication?

Tags: angular, loading, angular2-observables

I have a table component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'ag-table',
    template: `
        <span *ngIf="isLoading">Loading</span>
        <table class="table">
           rows loaded through @Input() rows;
        </table>
    `
})
```

Then I have a parent component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'ag-page',
    template: `
        <ag-table [rows]=rows></ag-table>
    `
})
```

Now, in ag-page, I need to get data from the server, so I'm making the http request through a service, let's say page.service.ts. In this moment, I want to show a loading indication in my ag-table.

Which is the best approach?

1. Get the component instance through ag-page using @ViewChild and setting the isLoading to true?
2. Create a table.service.ts, inject it to TableComponent and use observables to detect when data is loading.
3. Another suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if the input `rows` is set.

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'ag-table',
    template: `
        <span *ngIf="!rows">Loading</span>
        <table class="table">
           rows loaded through @Input() rows;
        </table>
    `
})
export class AgTable {
    @Input()
    rows:Row[];
}
```

When the application start, `ag-page` don't have any rows so the variable `rows`  passed to `ag-table` is undefined. So the test `!rows` return true and your loading span is displayed.

At the end of the asynchronous load, `ag-page` override its rows with the new value. With the input binding the rows are given to `ag-table`. So the test `!rows` is now false and the loading span is removed.

Comment: Interesting, it's soo simple and I thought I could do it only in these complicated ways... How about when I hit a refresh data button in ag-page, then I need to set this.rows = undefined; again and repeat the process, right?

Comment: Yeah if you want to add a refresh button in ag-page, you just have to `delete this.rows` or `this.rows = null` or something like that. I just realize you can do it even easier (I have made an edit)

Comment: Do not forget to validate the answer if it answered your need.